# Is it possible to integrate FingerPrint reader with asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, fingerprint

Is it possible to integrate a fingerprint reader with asp.net? Are there any C# libraries available for detecting fingerprints? How to get Started? Any suggestions?

I have no idea how to start to code the program that will store, retrieve and compare the fingerprint.

Comment: Do you actually have some device to do the detecting? You can't just go ahead and detect finger prints without a device designed to actually capture the information. And once you have such a device it will come with drivers that let you connect to it via the appropriate language.

Comment: @silky i dont have any device.. Even i dont know how to get started with FingerPrint detection?

Comment: @Pandiya: Buy a device that detects fingerprints.

Comment: Better just to have ASP.NET display a black page and blow some chalk dust at your screen.

Comment: Best yet; don't ever detect fingerprints because biometrics in general are a really terrible approach to security. I personally boycott use (but that's easy currently).

Comment: I don't see how it would be possible without running code on the computer where the fingerprint reader is actually attached - I assume that would *not* be the server running ASP.NET.

Comment: @codeka: I'm sure you could easily think of ways it could be done (image upload, some javascript, silverlight control, etc, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know how to retrieve fingerprints, but it seems to me if you want to integrate this function with asp.net, you have to use flash/activex/silverlight and stuff like that. You must have some client side application installed to do the job for you.